# How to solve red-cross overlay on build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle

**There is a red cross overlay on my build.gradle.** It is annoying because i am not able to pin-point where it is coming from.

**Some information about my project:**

```
1. I am using sts-3.9.8.RELEASE as IDE
2. It is a spring boot project, 2.1.7.RELEASE
3. In gradle-wrapper.properties, i am using v5.5
4. When i run a build or a bootWar task, both tasks run successfully.
5. The rootProject.name in settings.gradle, matches the project name in sts.
6. I can run the spring boot application successfully, and i can access the end-points without any issue.
```

I have tried deleting the build directory of the project, as i thought there could be some old settings that is upsetting gradle, but no.

I have also tried to right-click on the project, click on Gradle, click on Refresh Gradle Project, to no avail.

I have also tried to refresh the project, but still no, the red cross is still there.

**Contents of my build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.somename'
//version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    ...
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Any help or pointers as to what is upsetting gradle is most welcome.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

**Deleting the build directory and re-building was the solution**. The red-cross overlay was still visible on my `build.gradle`, because in the midst of trying things, i changed the `gradle` version to the latest `v5.6.2` and did not notice that an error appeared in the `Problems` view pane. In short, it said that it can't run a build with that distribution.

---

#### New Issue:

~ 2 years later, with `v7.1.1`, i stumbled upon my own question/answer which did not help me this time. If you are interested, i posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900715/whats-wrong-with-my-build-gradle-sourcesets-srcdir).

Comment: have answered the solution that worked for me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900715/whats-wrong-with-my-build-gradle-sourcesets-srcdir