# What's wrong with my build.gradle - sourceSets - srcDir

Tags: gradle

This is my sourceSets configuration in `build.gradle v7.1.1`:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/test/resources/sql"
        }
    }
}
```

And when i run `gradlew clean test`, it's working fine i.e BUILD SUCCESSFUL. But, i am seeing a red-cross overlay as follows on my IDE(`Spring Tool Suite v4.11.1.RELEASE` if that matters):
[image] and this is the corresponding `Problems view` pane error:
 [image]
When i remove the `srcDir` configuration, there is no more red-cross overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. And when navigated to the Problems Panel, it was showing the error message caused by the old builds. When I **manually deleted the error message** and rebuild the project, the issue was resolved.

Seems like **some cache issue** with eclipse.